# JQuery - asynchronous class constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, jquery-deferred, deferred

Here's my "class" (extended prototype) and its constructor:

```
encsTable = function(encsData) {
    var that = this;
    var drfrd = $.Deferred();
    this.init(encsData).done(function(){
        drfrd.resolve(that);
    });
    return $.when(drfrd).done().promise();
}

$.extend(encsTable.prototype, {
    init: function(encsData) {
        var drfrd = $.Deferred();
        $.each(encsData, function(index, val){
            /* 
              ...
              Some async AJAX calls 
              ...
            */
            if (index == encsData.length - 1){
                drfrd.resolve();
            }
        });
        return $.when(drfrd).done().promise();
    }
});
```

I'm struggling with creating a new object of the `encsTable`. Here's how I currently do it:

```
newEncsTable = new encsTable(encs).done(function(val){
    val.some_method();
});
```

As you can see it's not a good way of doing it. The `newEncsTable` isn't an `encsTable` object, it's a Promise object instead. In order to access other methods of `encsTable` I have to use the `val` variable. I'd like to do something like this:

```
newEncsTable = new encsTable(encs).done().get_return_value();
newEncsTable.some_method();
```

I know that it's not how deferred objects work, but is there any workaround?

## Answer:

I had to wait for the constructor to finish before executing the  `some_method` function, because I was using private properties of the `encsTable` class inside this function. Some of those properties were depending on AJAX calls executed inside the constructor.
I decided to move the AJAX calls from the constructor to the `some_method` function. Thanks to that I got rid of the promises in the constructor.

Comment: There's a workaround in classical JavaScript, is it necessary to use promises and jQuery here?

Comment: @AndrueAnderson No, I don't have to use jQuery.

Comment: Using Object.create(inheritFrom) will provide the functionality I believe you're in need of. It creates an object whose prototype is 'inheritFrom' - giving access to all the functions